# pandas apply custom functions to rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df and a bunch of custom functions written to do data checks on survey data.  We have a number of exceptions where certain data checks should or should not be done - these are based off a categorical variable or a date variable.  When doing something like this:

```
def data_check(df):
    if df[string_col]== 'some string':
        df = package.f1(df, other_col1)
    df = package.f2(df, other_col1, other_col2)
    if df[date_col]> some_datetime_obj:
        df = package.f3(df, other_col3)
    return(df)

clean_df = data_check(dirty_df)
```

I get this error:
`Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`

Thanks!!

Comment: You are comparing a series `df[string_col]` to a string 'some string'. Therefore, the output will be a series. As the error message says, you need to be specific about what you are testing, e.g. are all or any of the Boolean series output meant to be True?

Answer (score 0):

`df[string_col]` is a column, but 'some string' is a single string. When you do `df[string_col]== 'some string'`, the comparison `=='some string'` is broadcast over the column. You get a separate boolean for each value in the column, but the `if` is expecting a single boolean.

Also, when you indent, what you write is automatically interpreted as code. You don't need to both indent and enclose in grave marks. (Grave marks are these things: `)